# On duplicate key update feature in H2

Tags: sql, h2

I have developed java desktop application with the use of H2(Embedded). I just have basic knowledge about database, so i simply installed H2 and create a schema name RecordAutomation and then add tables to that schema. Now i am trying to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE feature for a specific table which is not working giving sql syntax error, i check my query i found it right, given below

```
INSERT INTO RECORDAUTOMATION.MREPORT 
(PRODUCTID ,DESCRIPTION ,QUANTITY ,SUBTOTAL ,PROFIT ) 
VALUES (22,olper,5,100,260) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY+5;
```

i search and try to solve this problem some where it is discussed like this feature does not work for non-default tables. i have no idea about default and non-default. please make help me

Comment: There is no such syntax, see the manual: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#insert you are looking for the `MERGE` statement: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this works in mysql... i need query which could perform update on duplicating key

Comment: Well H2 is not MySQL. As I said: you are looking for the MERGE statement.

Comment: This is not property documented... this feature is supported, but only int the MySQL mode so far.

Answer (score 25):

You need to use the MySQL mode. To do that, append `;mode=MySQL` to the database URL. (This feature is not properly documented yet).

The table needs to have a primary key or at least a unique index. Complete example:

```
drop table MREPORT;

set mode MySQL;

create table MREPORT(PRODUCTID int primary key, 
DESCRIPTION varchar, QUANTITY int,  SUBTOTAL int, PROFIT int);

INSERT INTO MREPORT 
(PRODUCTID ,DESCRIPTION ,QUANTITY ,SUBTOTAL ,PROFIT ) 
VALUES (22,'olper',5,100,260) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE QUANTITY = QUANTITY+5;
```

Comment: Feature not supported: "Unable to apply ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, no index found!"; i apply MySQL mode but still it is not working

Comment: Yes, that's a different problem. "no index found" means, well "no index found". I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: thanks for help. first time when table was empty your query works fine but second when data is duplicated i am getting this error: 
Column "PUBLIC.MREPORT.PRODUCTID" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO recordautomation.MREPORT (PRODUCTID ,DESCRIPTION ,QUANTITY ,SUBTOTAL ,PROFIT ) 
VALUES (22,'olper',5,100,260) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE QUANTITY = QUANTITY+5

Comment: Yes, this is fixed in version 1.4.187. Before that, the MySQL compatibility feature "insert ... on duplicate key update" did not work with a non-default schema.

Comment: If you are getting this error in a version of H2 below 1.3.187 you can work around that bug by making sure you set the current schema to the one used by the table you are querying. @rockledgeDev could resolve his problem by first calling `SET SCHEMA recordautomation;`

Comment: @ThomasMueller - It doesn't appear to be working in 1.4.192 either. If the schema is set to TEST_1, the error that shows up:

`Column "TEST_1" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO test_1.sample_table (account_id, sample_col_1, sample_col_2) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test_1.sample_table.sample_col_1 = ?, test_1.sample_table.sample_col_2 = ? [42122-187]`

Comment: The same occurs for the `REPLACE INTO..` non-standard MySql syntax.

Comment: @navkast please ask a separate question

Comment: I was having the exact issue as the OP.  Appending ";mode=MySQL" to the url fixed it.  Thanks.