# ON DUPLICATE KEY support in H2

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, h2

I use h2 for testing purpose in a Spring Boot (& spring data JPA) application.

I'm storing some sort of statistic per day, and therefore I set up ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE queries to store those statistics. If nothing has been stored for the given day, create a new entry. If this day is already in the database, just increment its value.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE statistic (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  my_date DATE UNIQUE,
  value_1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  value_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  value_3 INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  ...
  value_X INTEGER DEFAULT 0
)
```

Repo:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO statistic (value_X, my_date) SELECT :valueX,, :myDate " +
        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value_X, = value_X, + :valueX,", nativeQuery = true)
void saveOrIncrementValueX(@Param("valueX") Integer valueX, @Param("myDate") LocalDate myDate);
```

Finally I've tweaked H2 so the mySQL mode is used

```
my_schema.datasource.jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:my_schema;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL
```

When I run a test that simply tries to store values multiple times for the same day, it works the first time, then an exception is thrown saying that a duplicate key is being inserted:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_SQNR5X4KWWB6W0IXLL4HURKTF_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.STATISTIC(MATCH_DATE) VALUES (DATE '2018-03-06', 1)"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO statistic (version_ok, match_date) SELECT ?, ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE version_ok = version_ok + ? [23505-185]
o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UK_SQNR5X4KWWB6W0IXLL4HURKTF_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.STATISTIC(MATCH_DATE) VALUES (DATE '2018-03-06', 1)"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO statistic (version_ok, match_date) SELECT ?, ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE version_ok = version_ok + ? [23505-185]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

I bet mySQL support is not fully functional in H2, but did I miss something? Is there something I can do to make "ON DUPLICATE KEY" work properly?

EDIT: I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809219/on-duplicate-key-update-feature-in-h2) but I have a different error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On duplicate key update feature in H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809219/on-duplicate-key-update-feature-in-h2)

Comment: @dognose I had a look at this post and followed it for the most part, but I have a different error at the end.