# On Duplicate Key Failure in H2

Tags: java, sql, database, testing, h2

Table Creation Query

```
CREATE TABLE A (
      COLUMN1 VARCHAR(255),
      COLUMN2 INT,
      PRIMARY KEY(COLUMN1)
);
```

Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO A (COLUMN1, COLUMN2)  VALUES ('www.google.com', 10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN2=10;
```

**ERROR**:
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [DATA/testdata.sql]: INSERT INTO A (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES ('www.google.com', 10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN2=10; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO A (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES ('www.google.com', 10) [*]ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN2=10"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO A (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES ('www.google.com', 10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COLUMN2=10 [42000-210]

**gradle**: testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.1.210'

**dbUrl**: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE

Comment: This?: [On duplicate key update feature in H2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29809219/3890632)

Comment: Yeah. Tried the solutions mentioned there but nothing worked. I am already on the latest version of h2 and also have setup the mode in URL correctly

Comment: Your test case (with appended comma after `INT` missed in definition of your table) doesn't throw any exceptions in MySQL compatibility mode of H2 2.1.210.